# Ionic angularjs page navigation not working in devices

Tags: angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework

```
app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider
.state('Login',{
    url:'/Login',
    templateUrl:'./templates/Login.html',

})
.state('home',{
    url:'/home',
    templateUrl:'./templates/home.html',
    controller:'TicketsCtrl',

})
.state('ticket',{
    url:'/ticket/:Id',
    templateUrl:'./templates/ticket.html',
    controller:'TicketDetailsCtrl',

});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Login");});
```

This is my app.js file
1.If i run with the bellow coding the navigation is not working.

```
ionic run android
```

In this i'm only getting the first screen i.e Login if i authenticate I'm getting the message but not navigating to the next page

2.If i run with the bellow coding the navigation is working.

```
ionic run android -l -c
```

May be the problem is the server is disconnected in 1 and not disconnected in server 2.
How can i resolve this one.

Comment: check your console, there must be an error

Answer (score 0):

It might not be working because of incorrect templateUrl. This relative path read in android device might fail.

Remove "." and "/" from url

```
.state('home',{
  url:'/home',
  templateUrl:'templates/home.html',// <--- in this line
  controller:'TicketsCtrl'
```

Comment: I tried but not worked.If that is the problem it will also not work in 2'nd case.